# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'FOT' to data type int

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

```
String start_cd;
String end_cd;
opencon();

SqlCommand res = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID,'" + start_cd + "','" + end_cd + "' FROM Train_route_up WHERE '" + start_cd + "'!=0 or '" + end_cd + "'!=0", con);
SqlDataAdapter sda_res = new SqlDataAdapter(res);
DataTable dt_res = new DataTable();
sda_res.Fill(dt_res);

listBox1.DataSource=dt_res;
listBox1.DisplayMember=" +start_cd+ ";
//Train_route_up=  SQL table name
//FOT=start_cd value(nvarchar)
```

I get this as an error: ***Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'FOT' to data type int***. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: what are your table columns?

Comment: sql table column name=FOT, Data type=int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is an error the SQL Server produces when a string cannot be converted to an integer, in a context where the database thinks this is necessary.

You have these expressions in the `where` clause:

```
'" + start_cd + "'!=0 or '" + end_cd + "'!=0
```

You are explicitly comparing a string (in single quotes) to an integer (0).  This is one of those situations.  This will generate the error if the string is not in a numeric format.

I don't know what you want to do, perhaps one of the following:

Compare to the string `'0'`

```
'" + start_cd + "'!='0' or '" + end_cd + "'!='0'
```

Compare to NULL

```
'" + start_cd + "' is not null or '" + end_cd + "' is not null
```

Refer to column names and not a string:

```
" + start_cd + "!=0 or " + end_cd + "!=0
```

Comment: i used this solution " + start_cd + "!=0 or " + end_cd + "!=0 but listbox show System.Data.DataRowView (my sql table column Data type int)