# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '06-03-21' to data type int

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, visual-studio-code, ssms

I am trying to **compare a string variable** in my *Python* script **with a varchar variable in *SQL***. Following is a snippet from my code:

```
todaysDate = datetime.now().date().strftime('%d-%m-%y')

read(conn, f'select cou_id from NewCourier where date_created = {todaysDate}'
```

Where:

`todaysDate` => variable in python storing current date

`cou_id` & `date_created` => columns in a relational DB table *NewCourier*

I tried:

`read(conn, f'select cou_id from NewCourier where CAST(date_created AS INT) = {todaysDate}`

I've also gone through a couple of questions and solutions on StackOverflow and other sites and found only [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21806811/13018845) solution similar to my problem but I didn't get a clear idea of how to solve it.

Thanks!

**Python 3.8.5**

**Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a variable to store the current date in Python, I **used the `GETDATE()` method** of SQL and converted it to varchar **using the `CONVERT()` method** in SQL which solved my problem

(i.e., it allowed me to get the courier IDs of all the records generated on that particular day).

Here's the updated line:

`read(conn, f'select cou_id from NewCourier where date_created = CONVERT(varchar, getdate(), 23)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the column data type is integer and you are trying to compare it to a string.  If you can find code in your program that inserts into the table you should be able to figure out how to convert your date time properly

Comment: The column data type is `varchar(20)`